# NSUnknownKeyException this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key

Tags: swift, runtime, nstimer, nsunknownkeyexception

So I am working through a tutorial and I have made sure that I followed the author to the letter and my code throws the following error.

```
2014-10-01 22:26:14.545 stopwatch2[3503:861733] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<stopwatch2.ViewController 0x7c57f050> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key pause.'
```

My Question is:

**Based on the error provided what is the reason my application is failing ?**

Here's my code that won't compile:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var timer = NSTimer()

    @IBOutlet var time : UILabel!
    var count = 0

    @IBAction func play(sender : AnyObject) {

    timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: Selector("result"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }

    @IBAction func pause(sender : AnyObject) {
        timer.invalidate()
    }


    @IBAction func reset(sender : AnyObject) {
        timer.invalidate()
        count = 0
        time.text="0"
    }



    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.



    }

    func result() {
        count++
        time.text = String(count)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

What I would really like to know, is how to investigate this on my own because I am sure the authors other videos will yield the same results.

The videos are from udemy.com, The Complete iOS8 and Swift Course..

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key pause"  usually means you have a referencing outlet problem.  Look in the Connections Inspector for your different buttons. You may likely either have:

2 referencing outlets for one button and the program does not know which ne to use, etc.

I ran the code hooking up 1 label to an IBOutlet and three buttons (play, pause, reset), one to each IBAction, and it ran perfectly.

Comment: problem solved, thank you. I'll try to remember to up vote once I have privelages.

Comment: @user1664443 I can upvote for you :-) If the answer works for you remember to accept it

Comment: My brain can't figure out how Apple can't include a check for this in XCode.